# msal.js and microsoft graphi API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have a web application that is already built using spring boot.

I would need to include some data into this application about office 365 emails .I understand that i can fetch the data from office 365 emails using Microsoft Graph.

I am confused though about what type of application should i build.

As per the docs here
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_register_app_v2

Web apps:
redirect URL is the location in your app that the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint calls when it has processed 
the authentication request 
This means i need to run some kind of webserver where microsoft will do a callback after authentication.

Native or mobile apps:
The redirect URI is a unique URI provided for your application to ensure that messages sent to that URI 
are only sent to that application.
This means its a pure javascript application where i need not run any kind of webserver.

Since my requirement is to integrate this functionality into another existing app i am inclined to go the native or webapp way.

The terminology used is a native or mobile app but what i have is a normal javascript based browser app .

Am i correct in assuming that what microsoft calls a native or web app is the correct choice for my usecase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to choose web application as the application type. The redirect URL is the web page from your web app where the end user is sent after an authentication token has been retrieved on their behalf.

Since I can't find a v2 auth client library (MSAL for Java), I suggest that you try the following:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java

Update:
There's the recently released preview [Microsoft Graph SDK for Java](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java) for accessing O365 data.